# Angular stagger animation custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, angularjs-directive, ng-animate

I have an ng-view that loads an HTML file with a directive:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', ['ngAnimate']).directive('pageList', ['$animate', function($animate){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/templates/list.html',
    controller: function($scope){
        $scope.items = [
        'Page 1',
        'Page 2',
        'Page 3',
        'Page 4',
        'Page 5'
        ];
}
}]);
```

with the following as the contents of list.html:

```
<div id="list-wrap">
<ul id="page-list">
    <li class="page-list-item" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="tapHandle(this)">
        <span class="page-list-text">{{ item }}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Now, when the view is loaded, the content is rendered just fine and the ng-enter, ng-enter-active classes are attached to the wrapping element (the `<ng-view></ng-view>`). I want to be able to stagger the entrances of the `<li>` elements using `ng-stagger`, but that's only applied to elements of `ng-repeat`, which my `ng-view` is not. How can I do this?

There appears to be a guide of sorts here: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/12/staggering-animations-in-angularjs.html, but I can't follow how to apply it to my situation.

Thanks! I'm new to Angular so if there's a more "Angular" way to do it let me know.

Answer (score 2):

try this!

```
.page-list-item.ng-enter-stagger,
.page-list-item.ng-leave-stagger {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 0;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0;
    -o-transition-duration: 0;
    transition-duration: 0;
}

.page-list-item.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition:0.2s linear all;
    -moz-transition:0.2s linear all;
    -ms-transition:0.2s linear all;
    -o-transition:0.2s linear all;
    transition:0.2s linear all;

    -ms-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}


.page-list-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    -ms-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}

.page-list-item.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition:0.2s linear all;
    -moz-transition:0.2s linear all;
    -ms-transition:0.2s linear all;
    -o-transition:0.2s linear all;
    transition:0.2s linear all;

    -ms-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}

.page-list-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    -ms-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: You only need to use `transition` and `-webkit-transition` nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZceaB0Twapvqek37NnJp?p=preview)

In order to stagger your item animations on load, you need to populate your items array **after** the template has been linked.

So, the ideal place to do this is in your directive's (post) link function:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', ['ngAnimate']).directive('pageList', ['$animate', function($animate){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'list.html',
    controller: function($scope){
        $scope.data = [
        'Page 1',
        'Page 2',
        'Page 3',
        'Page 4',
        'Page 5'
        ];

        $scope.items = [];
        this.addItems = function() {
           for (var i in $scope.data) {
               $scope.items.push($scope.data[i]);
           }
        };
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        ctrl.addItems();
    }
}}]);
```

Note: this solution relies on the CSS posted by Jorge